# Updating/editing mysql data with lookup table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables:

```
Departments:

dept_id         dept_name

1       dept 1
2       dept 2
3       dept 3
4       dept 4

-------------

Hours:

hours_id    proj_hours
1       18
2       36

-------------

Project:

proj_id     proj_name
1       project1
2       project2

-------------

Summary:

Summary_id  proj_id     hours_id    dept_id
1       1       1       1
2       2       1       2
3       1       2       3
4       1       1       4

-----------------------------------------------------

SELECT *
FROM summary S
JOIN projects P ON S.proj_id = P.proj_id
JOIN departments D ON D.dept_id = S.dept_id
JOIN hours H ON H.hours_id = S.hours_id
```

---

I have an index.php table that neatly displays the join data from above with a broken edit function.....  I can't figure out how to update the actual values from the lookup table from a manual edit function.

`<td align="center"><a href="edit2.php?id=<?php echo $rows['summary_id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>`

is used to send the summary_id to the edit page, which it's defintely sending, but not the values.. I have blank fields.  From there, I'd like to have my fields ready to edit, but again, blank fields... I'm having a problem the "id's" as opposed to "values" and formatting that right.

Suggestions?

edit.php code:

```
<?php
        // Connect to server and select database.
        mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

        if(isset($_GET['summary_id']))  
        {
            $id = $_GET['summary_id'];
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM summary WHERE proj_id='$proj_id'");
            $rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);
        }
        if (isset($_POST['nproj_id']))  

        {
            $summary_id     = $_POST['summary_id'];     
            $nproj_id       = $_POST['nproj_id'];
            $nclarity_id    = $_POST['clarity_id'];
            $nhours_id      = $_POST['nhours_id'];
            $ndept_id       = $_POST['ndept_id'];
            $sql            = "UPDATE summary SET clarity_id='$nclarity_id' WHERE proj_id='$proj_id'" 
            or die ("couldn't update".mysql_error());

            $res            = mysql_query($sql) or die ("couldn't update".mysql_error());
                            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index2.php'>";
        }

?>


<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="edit2.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Clarity ID</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Hours</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Department</strong></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="nclarity_id" type="text" id="nclarity_id" value="<?php echo $rows['clarity_id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="nproj_hours" type="text" id="nproj_hours" value="<?php echo $rows['proj_hours']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="ndept_name" type="text" id="ndept_name" value="<?php echo $rows['dept_name']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>

<td>
<input name="summary_id" type="hidden" id="summary_id" value="<?php echo $rows['summary_id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Here's my index.php .... the corrections you made still didn't work. :(

```
<?php   
 // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

        if($_POST['submitted'])
        {
            $proj_id            = $_POST['proj_id'];
            $summary_id         = $_POST['summary_id'];
            $clarity_id         = $_POST['clarity_id'];
            $hours_id           = $_POST['hours_id'];
            $proj_hours         = $_POST['proj_hours'];
            $dept_name          = $_POST['dept_name'];
            $dept_id            = $_POST['dept_id'];

            $sqlinsert      = "INSERT INTO summary (summary_id,proj_id,hours_id,dept_id) VALUES (NULL,
            '$proj_id','$hours_id','$dept_id'";


            if (!mysql_query($sqlinsert)) {
            die('error inserting new record'.mysql_error());
        } // end of the nested if statement


        }
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT *
                        FROM summary S
                        JOIN projects P ON S.proj_id = P.proj_id
                        JOIN departments D ON D.dept_id = S.dept_id
                        JOIN hours H ON H.hours_id = S.hours_id
                        LIMIT 0 , 30");


    ?>

    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    Clarity #: <input type="text" name="clarity_id"><br />
    Estimated Hours: <input type="text" name="proj_hours"><br /> 
    Department: <input type="text" name="dept_name"><br />

    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>
    <input type="submit" value="enter">
    </form>



    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td align="center"><strong>Clarity#</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>Estimated Hours</strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong>Department</strong></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $rows['clarity_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['proj_hours']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['dept_name']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="edit2.php?id=<?php echo $rows['summary_id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    }
    ?>

    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: you need to select query in edit page and using id u can fetch value and display select query data in your field

Comment: I'm still learning, so I'm not quite sure I have the grasp of that one yet.. can you give me an example?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some corrections are made..try this

```
    <?php
    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    if(isset($_GET['summary_id']))  
    {
        $id = $_GET['summary_id'];
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM summary WHERE `summary_id`='$id'");//Correction is made here
        if($res){
        $rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);
        }
        else{
         echo "Fetch Error: ".mysql_error();
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))  //correction is here

    {
        $summary_id     = $_POST['summary_id'];     
        $nproj_id       = $_POST['nproj_id'];
        $nclarity_id    = $_POST['clarity_id'];
        $nhours_id      = $_POST['nhours_id'];
        $ndept_id       = $_POST['ndept_id'];
        $sql            = "UPDATE summary SET clarity_id='$nclarity_id' WHERE proj_id='$proj_id' AND `summary_id`='{$summary_id}'"; //correction is here

        if(mysql_query($sql)){echo "Update successful";}else{echo "couldn't update".mysql_error();}
                        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index2.php'>";
    }

    ?>


   <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
   <form name="form1" method="post" action="edit2.php">
   <td>
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="center"><strong>Clarity ID</strong></td>
   <td align="center"><strong>Hours</strong></td>
   <td align="center"><strong>Department</strong></td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="center">
   <input name="nclarity_id" type="text" id="nclarity_id" value="<?php echo $rows['clarity_id']; ?>">
   </td>
   <td align="center">
   <input name="nproj_hours" type="text" id="nproj_hours" value="<?php echo $rows['proj_hours']; ?>" size="15">
   </td>
   <td>
   <input name="ndept_name" type="text" id="ndept_name" value="<?php echo $rows['dept_name']; ?>" size="15">
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>

   <td>
   <input name="summary_id" type="hidden" id="summary_id" value="<?php echo $rows['summary_id']; ?>">
   </td>
   <td align="center">
   <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Update"> <!--correction is here-->
   </td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </td>
   </form>
   </tr>
   </table>

   <?php
   // close connection
   mysql_close();
   ?>
```

Comment: I added my index.php, as your corrections didn't seem to work. :(

Comment: Sorry! i didn't see your response... I actually solved this by going through and changing my code to something else to accomodate.  It's not pretty, but it works.  I have another issue, but am going to post that in a new post.  Thank you for your suggestions!